# Equality of Django's Q objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to compare django's [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) which are composed in the exact same way.

But despite all children and relations between them being same, they aren't deemed equal.

```
from django.db.models import Q

$ q1 = Q(a=1) & Q(b=1) & Q(c=1)

$ q2 = Q(a=1) & Q(b=1) & Q(c=1)

$ q1 == q2

$ False
```

This is posing problems in my unit tests where I build up filters for my querysets using Q objects.

Why are the two Q objects not equal?

I am using Django 1.11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django <= 1.11.x does not implement `__eq__` method for Q objects.
As can be seen [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/utils/tree.py).

Django >= 2.0 implements `__eq__` method for Q objects. [Code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.0.x/django/utils/tree.py#L66).

So it is not possible to directly check the equality of two Q objects before Django 2.0.

But it is possible to write a simple function that checks the equality of Q objects. We can directly use the code from the repo.

```
def compare_q(q1 , q2):
        return (
            q1.__class__ == q2.__class__ and
            (q1.connector, q1.negated) == (q2.connector, q2.negated) and
            q1.children == q2.children
        )
```

So, for older versions of Django we can do:

```
$ compare_q(q1 , q2)

$ True
```

Answer (score 2):

I built on xssChauhan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864573/equality-of-djangos-q-objects/47864574#47864574) to handle the case where you have nested Q objects:

```
def compare_Qs(Q1, Q2):
    if hasattr(Q1, 'children') and hasattr(Q2, 'children'):
        if (Q1.__class__ == Q2.__class__) and ((Q1.connector, Q1.negated)
            == (Q2.connector, Q2.negated)) and (len(Q1.children) ==
            len(Q2.children)):
            result = [compare_Qs(Q1.children[i], Q2.children[i]) for i in
                range(len(Q1.children))]
            return all(result)
    return (Q1 == Q2)
```